# In ArcMaps, I am trying to find main that has Structure Number set, but there is not an overlapping CP System feature

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

In ArcMaps, I am trying to find main that has Structure Number set, but there is not an overlapping CP System feature. Using the toolbox in arcMap, how would I go about this?

I've tried using intersect and erase tools but am not getting the expected results(getting way to many).